# Is it a good UI practice to have app bar in an app a gradient color?

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, android

My gradient color ranges from pink to orange for my login page. No question it's an attractive design. But for my user class (once logged in), should the app bar be a gradient designed color too (similar to pink to orange theme), or is it a better practice to have it a solid color? And what about buttons?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your app? What are your users trying to do? How long do they interact with it? Apps that are really tools for instance, rely on extraneous chrome receding to the background so users can manipulate and edit things (often document creation). Color can be used extensively in data driven apps to give status indications (like stock prices). Please give more context so we understand.

Comment: Kindly add a screenshot of the wireframe or the current app. I understand why you're asking this (most latest updates of famous apps are following it) but even in those apps, it works for some while it doesn't for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the famous apps that have used *gradient* in their apps are [Tinder](https://www.gotinder.com/), [FB Messenger](https://www.messenger.com/), [Skype mobile](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/1/15723594/microsoft-skype-redesign-features), Bookmyshow mobile, etc.

I have added links to some to point out some important points:

- First and foremost, most of these gradient usages are limited to icon design, primary action buttons and/or splash screens.
- Secondly, some apps, like Skype in their most recent update, have used it in places other than the above mentioned places and it **simply doesn't work**.
- Finally, about the app bar, **don't do it**. As important as it may seem, the user's focus is on the main screen and activities while the app bar simple stays on top unnoticed. It is only used for very specific actions and hence should have a neutral, single, color.